# How to make a div that contains a text extends its height when the browser becomes smaller?

Tags: html, css

Consider following code. There is a top bar that contains a long text

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div style="float:left;height:36px;line-height:36px;text-transform: none;">
        long text....
    </div>
</div>
```

For class topbar, I have this line,

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
```

which draws a underline for the topbar.

Usually there is no problem. The long text occupies one line. However, when I shrink browser width, the long text occupies two lines, and the underline remains at the original position.

So my question is how to make the topbar extends height when the long text occupies two lines? Probably I miss something in topbar css style?

Here is the topbar css style:

```
font-size: 19px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
padding: 11px 0 7px 0;
color: #737171;
text-transform: none;
```

Thanks.

Comment: use a clearfix if you have a boiler plate. The answer given by Tom Chung accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to underline the individual lines of text why not use

```
text-decoration: underline
```

Also if you want the height of the element to change use the min-height attribute instead of height.

Comment: I want to underline the top bar, not individual lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this.

```
.topbar:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

The clear:both helps to change the .topbar element height when there are more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your div's css:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```